# How to group ranges in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Here is the data that I would like to group.

```
Start      End
  2         4
  26        30
  5         9
  20        24
  18        19
```

Because I have 18 - 19 and 20 - 24. I would add these two together as 18 - 24. In this case the rule is (a, b) => b.start - a.end = 1 and the result would be

```
Start      End
  18        24
  2         9
  26        30
```

EDIT added last result row per comments below.

Comment: LINQ-To-What? Are you using a database?

Comment: @TimSchmelter right, LINQ to Objects

Comment: You might be able to do it with an aggregate, but assuming you're not working with a database and can do what you like, I'd probably write a custom operator with a yield to do it. Essentially you want to sort these into order then walk the list with lookahead merging ranges as appropriate.

Comment: LINQ-To-Objects is not a LINQ provider which uses a database.

Comment: The rule is not clear, why can't you add all to one group from 2-30?

Comment: @TimSchmelter, I corrected it a few minutes ago.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: the data represents ranges. `2-4`, `26-30`, etc. The integers `2-9` are covered as are `18-24`. There is nothing covering `10-17` so it can't be included in an aggregated range. I assume the final results should also have `26-30` unless it is being excluded because it isn't being aggregated to something.

Comment: You are right Chris. Let me edit the question

Comment: That's not how LINQ groups works! Grouping in LINQ is made by evaluating each item and grouping them by the result of the selections specified. You could have group colections with the consecuents items like you want, but not the way you want, just grouping the items into differents lists.

Comment: @frikinside Correct, the LINQ group by method doesn't really do this.  Fortunately you can create a custom grouping method that *does* support that behavior, and it's not terribly difficult.  It can also be written in a sufficiently general way as to be [rather widely applicable](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A1159478+groupwhile).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So we'll start with a helper method called `GroupWhile`.  It will be provided with a predicate accepting two items from the sequence, the previous and the current.  If that predicate returns true, the current item goes into the same group as the previous item.  If not, it starts a new group.

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupWhile<T>(
    this IEnumerable<T> source, Func<T, T, bool> predicate)
{
    using (var iterator = source.GetEnumerator())
    {
        if (!iterator.MoveNext())
            yield break;

        List<T> list = new List<T>() { iterator.Current };

        T previous = iterator.Current;

        while (iterator.MoveNext())
        {
            if (!predicate(previous, iterator.Current))
            {
                yield return list;
                list = new List<T>();
            }

            list.Add(iterator.Current);
            previous = iterator.Current;
        }
        yield return list;
    }
}
```

Once we have this we can order the items by the start, then by the end date, group them while the previous range's end overlaps with the next range's start, and then collapse each group into a new range based on the groups start and end values.

```
var collapsedRanges = ranges.OrderBy(range => range.Start)
    .ThenBy(range => range.End)
    .GroupWhile((prev, cur) => prev.End + 1 >= cur.Start)
    .Select(group => new Range()
    {
        Start = group.First().Start,
        End = group.Select(range => range.End).Max(),
    });
```